# StageXL Canvas always empty

Tags: dart, stagexl

I'm just new to Stagexl and Dart.

I'm reading the little starting guide on stageXL.org (http://www.stagexl.org/docs/getting-started.html) and I'm trying the sample code to draw a red circle and it doesn't work (the canvas is empty).

None of the samples I found on some page didn't work.

For example, this one with the four square: http://www.stagexl.org/docs/wiki-articles.html?article=introduction, the canvas is always empty..

Need some help ..

If you know a good tutorial for learning StageXl please share it to me !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of StageXL (version 0.12) does not support vector graphics when the WebGL renderer is used. Please opt-out from the WebGL renderer and use the Canvas2D renderer like this:

```
// do this before the Stage constructor is used
StageXL.stageOptions.renderEngine = RenderEngine.Canvas2D;
```

The next versions of StageXL (starting with 0.13) will support more vector graphics commands even when the WebGL renderer is used. Please be aware that WebGL is optimized for rendering textures (Bitmap/BitmapDatas) and drawing vector graphics may be a costly operation depending on the use case.